# Method is returning 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]' instead of the result

Tags: c#

I think it's an asynchronous task being left off at

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            }));
```

But I'm unsure of why it's occuring and replacing the output of another method. If in the following code `Auth()` runs successfully, then `UserData()` runs, why is it running into the error?

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security;
using System.Linq;
using AuthenticationResult = Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult;

namespace SharpZure
{
    public class SharpZure
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            var graphClient = await Auth();
            Console.WriteLine(UserData(graphClient));
        }
        public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> Auth()
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string token = null;
            IPublicClientApplication app;
            app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"]).WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs).Build();
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "Pass")        // you should fetch the password
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

            result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, "User@email.com", securePassword).ExecuteAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Using provided credentials to gather a token");
            token = result.AccessToken;

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            }));
            return graphClient;
        }
        static async Task UserData(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Display user details");
            var currentUser = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(currentUser.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't know which line this is coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as far as I can tell every async has a wait

Except this one:

```
Console.WriteLine(UserData(graphClient));
```

You never await the result of `UserData`, which is an `async` method.  So the returned value is simply a `Task`.  Await the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(await UserData(graphClient));
```

---

**Edit:** Upon further inspection... You're also not *returning* anything from `UserData`.  So while you need to await the result of the `Task`, there's no *value* to display.  Remove the `Console.WriteLine`:

```
await UserData(graphClient);
```

Comment: `var graphClient = await Auth();` is defined in Main, shouldn't that result be stored in that variable? which is then passed into `Console.WriteLine(UserData(graphClient));`

Comment: @Rooskyyy: The result of `Auth()` is indeed stored in that variable.  (Otherwise the call to `UserData(graphClient)` would be a compiler error.)  But the result of `UserData(graphClient)` is never awaited.  You're not writing the result fo the console, you're writing a `Task` to the console.  Await the result.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. However, when adding `await` to it, it throws an error: 

`Error CS1061 'GraphServiceClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'GraphServiceClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Rooskyyy: Where did you add the `await`?  Where are you trying to await a `GraphServiceClient`?  You need to await the `Task` being returned by `UserData(graphClient)`.

Comment: I did at it infront of UserData, but it gives an argument error: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'. If Main isn't stating void, why is the task void?

Comment: @Rooskyyy: I guess the next question becomes... What do you expect the output to be and why?  What are you returning from `UserData`?  (Hint: Nothing)

Comment: I'm expecting the output to be the result of the UserData() method. The method should print the current users display name
`var currentUser = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();`
`Console.WriteLine(currentUser.DisplayName);`

Comment: @Rooskyyy: I've updated the answer.  The `UserData` method produces output, but it doesn't *return* anything.  So you can't `Console.WriteLine` the result of that method, because there *is no* result.  Just call the method and `await` it, nothing more.

Comment: @Rooskyyy `async Task` is _kind of_ equivalent to `void` in non-async, so when you await it, you don't get a result because there isn't one.